# csscombの設定について。思ったように整形してくれません。

Tags: css, gulp

csscombの設定について

下記のサイトで作ったのですが意図した動きになりません
http://csscomb.com/config
私が作った設定

```
{

"remove-empty-rulesets": true,
"always-semicolon": true,
"color-case": "lower",
"block-indent": "\t",
"color-shorthand": true,
"element-case": "lower",
"eof-newline": true,
"leading-zero": false,
"quotes": "single",
"space-before-colon": " ",
"space-after-colon": " ",
"space-before-combinator": " ",
"space-after-combinator": " ",
"space-between-declarations": "\n",
"space-before-opening-brace": " ",
"space-after-opening-brace": "\n",
"space-after-selector-delimiter": " ",
"space-before-selector-delimiter": "",
"space-before-closing-brace": "\n",
"tab-size": true,
"unitless-zero": true,
"vendor-prefix-align": true

}
```

・下記のようにしたいのですが、

```
.c-headding-forth {
    z-index: 100;
    /* 縦書きを中央ぞろえにするため */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: inline;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* /縦書きを中央ぞろえにするため */
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,0,1), 1px 0px 0px #FF864B, 0px 1px 0px #FF864B, -1px 0px 0px #FF864B, 0px -1px 0px #FF864B;
}
```

・下記のようになってしまいます。

```
.c-headding-forth
{
    /* /縦書きを中央ぞろえにするため */
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    /* 縦書きを中央ぞろえにするため */

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    display: inline;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(255,255,0,1), 1px 0 0 #ff864b, 0 1px 0 #ff864b, -1px 0 0 #ff864b, 0 -1px 0 #ff864b;
}
```

具体的にどこをいじればよいのでしょうか？

またサブライムで手動でやるかgulpで最後にいっぺんにやるかどちらをやりますか？

gulpソース。排出はされますが、若干ずれて表記されます。

```
gulp.task('comb', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src-before/**/*.css')
    .pipe(csscomb()) // gulp-csscombで整形してあげて、
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest-after/comb'));//生成されたCSSの排出先。dest-after/cssの中に配置
});
```

・最後にプロパティの順番ですが皆さんどうしていますか？
私はモジラを採用しようかと思っているのですが、下記を追加すればそれだけでソートしてくれますか？まさか全部記載しないといけないのでしょうか？
display
list-style
position
float
clear
width
height
margin
padding
border
background
color
font
text-decoration
text-align
vertical-align
white-space
other text
content
CSS3

その後、下記のように変更したところ、サブライムテキストでの修正には成功しました。
ただ相変わらず、プロパティの順番の問題は残っています。

```
{
    "always-semicolon": true,
    "color-case": "lower",
    "block-indent": "\t",
    "color-shorthand": true,
    "element-case": "lower",
    "eof-newline": false,
    "leading-zero": false,
    "quotes": "double",
    "space-after-colon": " ",
    "space-between-declarations": "\n",
    "space-before-opening-brace": " ",
    "space-after-opening-brace": "\n",
    "space-before-closing-brace": "\n",
    "vendor-prefix-align": true
}
```

ただ下記の問題点があります。

```
/* Typography
   ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* * Web-Font "FontName" licensed under the SIL Open Font License * http://drinchev.github.io/monosocialiconsfont/ */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Mono Social Icons Font';
    src: url('../web-font/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot');
    src: url('../web-font/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../web-font/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../web-font/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../web-font/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.svg#MonoSocialIconsFont') format('svg');/*unuse*/
    src: url('../web-font/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

が下記のようになってしまいます。

```
/* Typography
   ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* * Web-Font "FontName" licensed under the SIL Open Font License * http://drinchev.github.io/monosocialiconsfont/ */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Mono Social Icons Font';
    src: url('../web-font/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot');
    src: url('../web-font/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../web-font/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../web-font/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../web-font/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.svg#MonoSocialIconsFont') format('svg');/*unuse*/
    src: url('../web-font/MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

またgulpで行った場合のみ下記のようになるのですが、内部の}をインデントしていますが、
これがもしかして普通なのでしょうか？
また、メモ帳で見るとなぜか改行がなくなります。

```
@media (min-width: 48em) {
    .c-social-btn--large {
        font-size: 7.5rem;
    }
}
```

・その後下記のようなソートを追加したところまた、思った通りに整形してくれなくなってしまいました。

ソース

```
{
    "always-semicolon": true,
    "color-case": "lower",
    "block-indent": "\t",
    "color-shorthand": true,
    "element-case": "lower",
    "eof-newline": false,
    "leading-zero": false,
    "quotes": "double",
    "space-after-colon": " ",
    "space-between-declarations": "\n",
    "space-before-opening-brace": " ",
    "space-after-opening-brace": "\n",
    "space-before-closing-brace": "\n",
    "vendor-prefix-align": true
    "sort-order": [ [
        "position",
        "top",
        "right",
        "bottom",
        "left",
        "z-index",
        "display",
        "visibility",
        "-webkit-flex-direction",
        "-moz-flex-direction",
        "-ms-flex-direction",
        "-o-flex-direction",
        "flex-direction",
        "-webkit-flex-order",
        "-moz-flex-order",
        "-ms-flex-order",
        "-o-flex-order",
        "flex-order",
        "-webkit-flex-pack",
        "-moz-flex-pack",
        "-ms-flex-pack",
        "-o-flex-pack",
        "flex-pack",
        "float",
        "clear",
        "-webkit-flex-align",
        "-moz-flex-align",
        "-ms-flex-align",
        "-o-flex-align",
        "flex-align",
        "-webkit-flex",
        "-moz-flex",
        "-ms-flex",
        "-o-flex",
        "flex",
        "overflow",
        "-ms-overflow-x",
        "-ms-overflow-y",
        "overflow-x",
        "overflow-y",
        "-webkit-overflow-scrolling",
        "clip",
        "-webkit-box-sizing",
        "-moz-box-sizing",
        "box-sizing",
        "margin",
        "margin-top",
        "margin-right",
        "margin-bottom",
        "margin-left",
        "padding",
        "padding-top",
        "padding-right",
        "padding-bottom",
        "padding-left",
        "min-width",
        "min-height",
        "max-width",
        "max-height",
        "width",
        "height",
        "outline",
        "outline-width",
        "outline-style",
        "outline-color",
        "outline-offset",
        "border",
        "border-spacing",
        "border-collapse",
        "border-width",
        "border-style",
        "border-color",
        "border-top",
        "border-top-width",
        "border-top-style",
        "border-top-color",
        "border-right",
        "border-right-width",
        "border-right-style",
        "border-right-color",
        "border-bottom",
        "border-bottom-width",
        "border-bottom-style",
        "border-bottom-color",
        "border-left",
        "border-left-width",
        "border-left-style",
        "border-left-color",
        "-webkit-border-radius",
        "-moz-border-radius",
        "border-radius",
        "-webkit-border-top-left-radius",
        "-moz-border-radius-topleft",
        "border-top-left-radius",
        "-webkit-border-top-right-radius",
        "-moz-border-radius-topright",
        "border-top-right-radius",
        "-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius",
        "-moz-border-radius-bottomright",
        "border-bottom-right-radius",
        "-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius",
        "-moz-border-radius-bottomleft",
        "border-bottom-left-radius",
        "-webkit-border-image",
        "-moz-border-image",
        "-o-border-image",
        "border-image",
        "-webkit-border-image-source",
        "-moz-border-image-source",
        "-o-border-image-source",
        "border-image-source",
        "-webkit-border-image-slice",
        "-moz-border-image-slice",
        "-o-border-image-slice",
        "border-image-slice",
        "-webkit-border-image-width",
        "-moz-border-image-width",
        "-o-border-image-width",
        "border-image-width",
        "-webkit-border-image-outset",
        "-moz-border-image-outset",
        "-o-border-image-outset",
        "border-image-outset",
        "-webkit-border-image-repeat",
        "-moz-border-image-repeat",
        "-o-border-image-repeat",
        "border-image-repeat",
        "-webkit-border-top-image",
        "-moz-border-top-image",
        "-o-border-top-image",
        "border-top-image",
        "-webkit-border-right-image",
        "-moz-border-right-image",
        "-o-border-right-image",
        "border-right-image",
        "-webkit-border-bottom-image",
        "-moz-border-bottom-image",
        "-o-border-bottom-image",
        "border-bottom-image",
        "-webkit-border-left-image",
        "-moz-border-left-image",
        "-o-border-left-image",
        "border-left-image",
        "-webkit-border-corner-image",
        "-moz-border-corner-image",
        "-o-border-corner-image",
        "border-corner-image",
        "-webkit-border-top-left-image",
        "-moz-border-top-left-image",
        "-o-border-top-left-image",
        "border-top-left-image",
        "-webkit-border-top-right-image",
        "-moz-border-top-right-image",
        "-o-border-top-right-image",
        "border-top-right-image",
        "-webkit-border-bottom-right-image",
        "-moz-border-bottom-right-image",
        "-o-border-bottom-right-image",
        "border-bottom-right-image",
        "-webkit-border-bottom-left-image",
        "-moz-border-bottom-left-image",
        "-o-border-bottom-left-image",
        "border-bottom-left-image",
        "background",
        "filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader",
        "background-color",
        "background-image",
        "background-attachment",
        "background-position",
        "-ms-background-position-x",
        "-ms-background-position-y",
        "background-position-x",
        "background-position-y",
        "-webkit-background-clip",
        "-moz-background-clip",
        "background-clip",
        "background-origin",
        "-webkit-background-size",
        "-moz-background-size",
        "-o-background-size",
        "background-size",
        "background-repeat",
        "box-decoration-break",
        "-webkit-box-shadow",
        "-moz-box-shadow",
        "box-shadow",
        "color",
        "table-layout",
        "caption-side",
        "empty-cells",
        "list-style",
        "list-style-position",
        "list-style-type",
        "list-style-image",
        "quotes",
        "content",
        "counter-increment",
        "counter-reset",
        "-ms-writing-mode",
        "vertical-align",
        "text-align",
        "-webkit-text-align-last",
        "-moz-text-align-last",
        "-ms-text-align-last",
        "text-align-last",
        "text-decoration",
        "text-emphasis",
        "text-emphasis-position",
        "text-emphasis-style",
        "text-emphasis-color",
        "text-indent",
        "-ms-text-justify",
        "text-justify",
        "text-outline",
        "text-transform",
        "text-wrap",
        "-ms-text-overflow",
        "text-overflow",
        "text-overflow-ellipsis",
        "text-overflow-mode",
        "text-shadow",
        "white-space",
        "word-spacing",
        "-ms-word-wrap",
        "word-wrap",
        "-ms-word-break",
        "word-break",
        "-moz-tab-size",
        "-o-tab-size",
        "tab-size",
        "-webkit-hyphens",
        "-moz-hyphens",
        "hyphens",
        "letter-spacing",
        "font",
        "font-weight",
        "font-style",
        "font-variant",
        "font-size-adjust",
        "font-stretch",
        "font-size",
        "font-family",
        "src",
        "line-height",
        "opacity",
        "-ms-filter:\\'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha",
        "filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity",
        "-ms-interpolation-mode",
        "-webkit-filter",
        "-ms-filter",
        "filter",
        "resize",
        "cursor",
        "nav-index",
        "nav-up",
        "nav-right",
        "nav-down",
        "nav-left",
        "-webkit-transition",
        "-moz-transition",
        "-ms-transition",
        "-o-transition",
        "transition",
        "-webkit-transition-delay",
        "-moz-transition-delay",
        "-ms-transition-delay",
        "-o-transition-delay",
        "transition-delay",
        "-webkit-transition-timing-function",
        "-moz-transition-timing-function",
        "-ms-transition-timing-function",
        "-o-transition-timing-function",
        "transition-timing-function",
        "-webkit-transition-duration",
        "-moz-transition-duration",
        "-ms-transition-duration",
        "-o-transition-duration",
        "transition-duration",
        "-webkit-transition-property",
        "-moz-transition-property",
        "-ms-transition-property",
        "-o-transition-property",
        "transition-property",
        "-webkit-transform",
        "-moz-transform",
        "-ms-transform",
        "-o-transform",
        "transform",
        "-webkit-transform-origin",
        "-moz-transform-origin",
        "-ms-transform-origin",
        "-o-transform-origin",
        "transform-origin",
        "-webkit-animation",
        "-moz-animation",
        "-ms-animation",
        "-o-animation",
        "animation",
        "-webkit-animation-name",
        "-moz-animation-name",
        "-ms-animation-name",
        "-o-animation-name",
        "animation-name",
        "-webkit-animation-duration",
        "-moz-animation-duration",
        "-ms-animation-duration",
        "-o-animation-duration",
        "animation-duration",
        "-webkit-animation-play-state",
        "-moz-animation-play-state",
        "-ms-animation-play-state",
        "-o-animation-play-state",
        "animation-play-state",
        "-webkit-animation-timing-function",
        "-moz-animation-timing-function",
        "-ms-animation-timing-function",
        "-o-animation-timing-function",
        "animation-timing-function",
        "-webkit-animation-delay",
        "-moz-animation-delay",
        "-ms-animation-delay",
        "-o-animation-delay",
        "animation-delay",
        "-webkit-animation-iteration-count",
        "-moz-animation-iteration-count",
        "-ms-animation-iteration-count",
        "-o-animation-iteration-count",
        "animation-iteration-count",
        "-webkit-animation-direction",
        "-moz-animation-direction",
        "-ms-animation-direction",
        "-o-animation-direction",
        "animation-direction",
        "pointer-events",
        "unicode-bidi",
        "direction",
        "-webkit-columns",
        "-moz-columns",
        "columns",
        "-webkit-column-span",
        "-moz-column-span",
        "column-span",
        "-webkit-column-width",
        "-moz-column-width",
        "column-width",
        "-webkit-column-count",
        "-moz-column-count",
        "column-count",
        "-webkit-column-fill",
        "-moz-column-fill",
        "column-fill",
        "-webkit-column-gap",
        "-moz-column-gap",
        "column-gap",
        "-webkit-column-rule",
        "-moz-column-rule",
        "column-rule",
        "-webkit-column-rule-width",
        "-moz-column-rule-width",
        "column-rule-width",
        "-webkit-column-rule-style",
        "-moz-column-rule-style",
        "column-rule-style",
        "-webkit-column-rule-color",
        "-moz-column-rule-color",
        "column-rule-color",
        "break-before",
        "break-inside",
        "break-after",
        "page-break-before",
        "page-break-inside",
        "page-break-after",
        "orphans",
        "widows",
        "-ms-zoom",
        "zoom",
        "max-zoom",
        "min-zoom",
        "user-zoom",
        "orientation"
    ] ]
}
```

整形後　プロパティをグループ分けして隙間が空いてしまいます。

```
.c-headding-forth
{
    /* /縦書きを中央ぞろえにするため */
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    /* 縦書きを中央ぞろえにするため */

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    display: inline;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(255,255,0,1), 1px 0 0 #ff864b, 0 1px 0 #ff864b, -1px 0 0 #ff864b, 0 -1px 0 #ff864b;
}
```

下記のような形が現場では多くないですか？もしかして今は上なのですか？

```
.c-headding-forth {
    z-index: 100;
    /* 縦書きを中央ぞろえにするため */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: inline;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* /縦書きを中央ぞろえにするため */
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,0,1), 1px 0px 0px #ff864b, 0px 1px 0px #ff864b, -1px 0px 0px #ff864b, 0px -1px 0px #ff864b;
}
```

Comment: ところで作成した設定 は `.csscomb.json`としてプロジェクトのルートに設置していますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

根本的な解決にはならないかもですが・・・

csscombで整形したあとに出力する前にgulp-sassでコンパイルしてあげると思う通りに整形されます。

```js
var sass = require("gulp-sass");　gulp-sassを呼んであげて
gulp.task('comb', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src-before/**/*.css')
    .pipe(csscomb()) // gulp-csscombで整形してあげて、

//この記述を
　　.pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}))
//挟んであげてください


    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest-after/comb'));//生成されたCSSの排出先。dest-after/cssの中に配置
});
```

プロパティの順番ですが
http://csscomb.com/config
公式にジェネレーターがありますので利用してはいかがでしょうか？
mozillaでも大丈夫だと思いますよ。
記載した分のみ並び替えを行うと思うので、全部記載する必要はないかと思います。
質問の意味を間違えていたらごめんなさい・・・

Comment: 公式のジェネレーター使ってたんですね　見落としすいません

Comment: ありがたいです。
私はpostcssを使っているのですが、それでもsassを挟んだ方が良いのですか？

Comment: 質問を編集しましたのでご覧ください。

Comment: https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js/blob/master/config/zen.json
現場ではどれを使っていますか
これらはおそらくライセンスフリーなのでさすがにライセンス表記などは不要ですよね
本当はモジラがあるとよかったのですがなさそうですね

Comment: emmentのソートを導入しました

Comment: うまくいかないので再質問します。